# DTCoreText file not found when import

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, dtcoretext

i have been trying to integrate the DTCoreText into my project.I followed the exact same procedures to add to the project.No matter what when i import the DTCoreText.h and run the app, it fails.Shows DTCoreText.h file not found.

Is there any other library parallel for DTCoreText.

Comment: DTFoundation is an external lib, maybe you are missing something from that?

Comment: have you tried integrating DTCoreText as a static framework?